# Why is my monitor turning off after inactivity when power settings tell it not to?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, hdmi, power-management, amd-radeon

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro and a Radeon HD 6670 with the latest ATI drivers. I've noticed lately (maybe within the past month or two) that my HDMI out will turn off after not being at the computer for some time when clearly the power settings in control panel tell my monitor to never turn off. There is nothing that I can see in my ATI control center that would have anything to do with power settings, so I presume that's not the case.

Where else can I look to make sure my screen isn't turning off when it shouldn't be?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/92693/dont-sleep-keeps-your-windows-machine-awake/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the computer is not falling to sleep or hibernation as when the computer is in sleep mode or hibernated the screen is automatically turned off or at standby mode. So be sure to check that the computer doesn't sleeps.

Comment: It's not sleeping for certain. I have music playing in the background and when I touch the mouse or keyboard the screen comes back on.

Comment: can you post me the snaps of your power management options? Could be a more helpful in answering.